# Padrino app with REST API

Tags: ruby, rest, sinatra, padrino

Within a Padrino application I have a **posts** controller with the conventional routes:

```
Blog::App.controllers :posts do

  get :index do
    ...
  end

  get :show, :with => :id do
    ...
  end

end
```

This gives me therefore the normal URL access within the **posts** namespace

```
http://blog.dev/posts
http://blog.dev/posts/show/1
```

Now I want to provide access through a REST API from a different route *outside the namespace*, like for example:

```
http://blog.dev/api/v1/post/all
http://blog.dev/api/v1/post/1
```

How can I define the API for my **posts** controller with routes outside its normal namespace?

I must admit that I am not sure if my approach is the common one. I could define a new **API V1** controller but in that case, I will have to duplicate information about **posts** in two different places.

In case this should be done with an **API** controller, I wonder which gems and/or conventions are commonly use for this task. Ideally I would like something that coordinates different API versions with the current model object.

Comment: [This](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning) is a rails tutorial. Though, I see no reason why the main logic could not be used in your case.

Comment: You're client and API should be separate. The client could then call the API for data, rather than being the API under a different namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Blog::App.controllers :posts, map: '/api/v1/posts' do

  get :index do
    ...
  end

end
```

And then, if you want add new versions of that controller

```
Blog::App.controllers :v2_posts, map: '/api/v2/posts' do

  get :index do
    ...
  end

end
```

(Yeah, it seems you can't have several files with the same controller with different `map` values.)

So, this won't work (sorry if that works, that doesn't when I tried) correctly and will cause issues :

```
Blog::App.controllers :posts, map: '/api/v1/posts' do

  get :index do
    ...
  end

end

Blog::App.controllers :posts, map: '/api/v2/posts' do

  get :index do
    ...
  end

end
```